# How to SUID? Shellscript, Perlscript, Binary-Wrapper?

Tags: suid

I just read some articales about suid.

lets say i need the helpdesk to be able to change customer passwords.
it would be good if i could execute a ruby script that checks the db if the user is a customer
(i dont want the helpdesk to change roots password)
and then it runs "passwd user" on it

what would be a **secure** way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The current trend is to use `sudo`.

Comment: last year alone 4 sudo vulnerabilities. sudo seems to suck

Comment: @banditj: and so much more security vulnerabilities related to SUID scripts and executables...